# Epimorphisms from an affine scheme?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be an affine scheme. Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be an integral morphism that is an epimorphism in the category of schemes. Is $Y$ affine?

Comment: No, take $X=\mathbf{A}^2 \setminus C$ where $C$ is a curve passing through $0$ which does not contain a line. Then we have a surjection $X\to \mathbf{P}^1$.

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jouanolou%27s_trick

Comment: Or how about F = elliptic curve E less a pt and FxF -> E being group addition ? Won't that work too ?

Comment: @aginensky yes, that works too.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger is your morphism really integral? I kind of have hard time reconciling your claim with this: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05YU

Comment: @StepanBanach You are right, I didn't notice this assumption! Of course my examples are not integral.

Comment: By the way, is there an example of a morphism as in the question which is not surjective (so that the result from Stacks Project does not apply)? Integral implies closed, and the image is dense, so it should be surjective.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger Eric Wofsey says you need some reducedness assumption for density: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2378504/epimorphisms-in-the-category-of-separated-schemes

Comment: Other than that, yes it appears that your logic works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92387/discussion-between-piotr-achinger-and-stepan-banach).